# PHP torrent tracker configuration

Tags: php, configuration

I'm trying to improve performance in a [torrent tracker site](http://www.trackerx.com.ar). But I've been running with some troubles. It has started to work real slow, and hung up from time to time.

I want to reconfigure PHP and Apache, the main idea is to add RAM to the server, and give more memory to PHP `memory_limit`.

How much memory is recommended for a tracker with 15000 peers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking this should be on serverfault. But generally you should figure out how much memory 1 peer uses, then multiply by # of peers and leave something like 20% headroom. What does the tracker software you use recommend?

**Edit**
I took a look at the phpbttracker+ project, not sure if this is what you are using, but it [recommends a p4 1.6 and 1gb of ram for 10,000 connected peers.](http://phpbttrkplus.sourceforge.net/#capabilities) This is with a 1MBit connection.

Trackers are fairly CPU intensive so throw as much cpu power at it as you can afford.

Comment: Hi Byron, thanks for answer so quickly!

It says nothing. I've no idea. How can i measure how much memory each peer uses?

Comment: I've seen that. But what i can't figure is the PHP configuration. It gets better when increased the memory_limit and the query_cache from MySQL. I'll keep trying.